# Why does it not go to any thing but "Equilateral: Three equal sides"

Tags: java

I have made this code to see what kind of triangle, but it just gives one answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String tal1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first side of the triangle ");
    Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(tal1);

    String tal2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second side of the triangle");
    Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(tal2);

    String tal3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Third side of the triangle");
    Double d3 = Double.parseDouble(tal3);

    if (d1<0 || d2<0 || d3 < 0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"trinagle not 0");

    else if (d1 >= (d2+d3) || d3 >= (d2+d1) || d2 >= (d1+d3) )
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not a triangle");

    else if (d1==d2 && d1==d3 && d2==d3 )
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Equilateral: Three equal sides");

    else if ((d1==d2 && d2!=d3) || (d1!=d2 && d3==d1) || (d3==d2 && d3!=d1) )
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Isosceles: Two equal sides");

    else if(d1!=d2 && d2!=d3 && d3!=d1)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Escalene: No equal sides");

    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"wrong");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

I have change some of the code but dont know what to do.

Comment: compare with equals, not with ==, or use `double` instead of `Double` if you want to compare with ==

Comment: You can compare `double` with == but not `Double`. `Double` needs `equals`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Oops, misread. The formatting got me.

Comment: thank you for the response. come on the same answer just before I checked up here

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Double` to `double` fixes the issue. You could also have changed `==` to `equals` to compare the values of the `Double` objects.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String tal1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first side of the triangle ");
    double d1 = Double.parseDouble(tal1);

    String tal2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second side of the triangle");
    double d2 = Double.parseDouble(tal2);

    String tal3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Third side of the riangle");
    double d3 = Double.parseDouble(tal3);

    if (d1 < 0 || d2 < 0 || d3 < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "trinagle not 0");
    } else if (d1 >= (d2 + d3) || d3 >= (d2 + d1) || d2 >= (d1 + d3)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a triangle");
    } else if (d1 == d2 && d1 == d3 && d2 == d3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Equilateral: Three equal sides");
    } else if ((d1 == d2 && d2 != d3) || (d1 != d2 && d3 == d1) || (d3 == d2 && d3 != d1)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Isosceles: Two equal sides");
    } else if (d1 != d2 && d2 != d3 && d3 != d1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Escalene: No equal sides");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "wrong");
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are comparing objects and no values.

So you could change  Double to double to compare values or you could change the operators - for example change d1 == d2 into sd1.equals(d2).